# How to restrict profile from using custom button from visual force component

Tags: visualforce-component

I have a visual force component on customobject page layout. I want that some profile users can only veiw the page and cannot use the custom button of that page. How can i achieve that.

Comment: I dont think there is a configuration way to achieve this. This should be customized by setting the conditions in VF Page and its Controller. We can get User Profile Id from UserInfo and based on it we can specify the conditions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If buttons are on that Visualforce Component (this is how I got this) than you can add something like:

```
<apex:commandButton value="Save" disabled="{!IF(CONTAINS($Profile.Name,'System Admin'),true,false)}" />
```

Comment: It works,Perfect..Thanks Andri.Z.. Could you also tell how to hide section same way..Thanks A lot.